# Subversion merging a branch into trunk causes files to appear unversioned

Tags: svn

I recently attempted to merge my branch back into the trunk. Everything seemed to complete successfully except that the file list seemed extremely short. After the merge, svn status showed that a lot of files were unversioned. However, if I rename the parent directory and do an svn up, the files repopulate. svn info shows that the files are actually part of the repository too. I'd like to know why the files that got merged into the original checkout show up as unversioned and what I need to do to get them to show up as actually being part of the repository without having to commit them again.

As a side note, svn add will allow me to add the file again, but I'm afraid to actually commit it because I'm not sure what it'll do to the version that's already in the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem was i was merging incorrectly. i tried to merge the branch back into the trunk without first doing a final merge from the trunk into the branch. i also did the merge from the branch into the trunk without specifying --reintegrate. once i reverse merged my trunk then performed those two steps, everything worked correctly.